# How to save a copy of XML file when performing any operation on it?

Tags: xml, vb6, xml-parsing

I am creating a VB6 application, which reads information from an XML file and then copies a particular file to my local workstation. The XML looks something like the below;

```
<ArrayOfMediaFile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <MediaFile>
    <fileName>Default.jpg</fileName> 
    <filePath>C:\Program Files\media</filePath> 
    <dateModified>2012-04-30T14:41:28.6893988-05:00</dateModified> 
    <Action>Add</Action> 
  </MediaFile>
  <MediaFile>
    <fileName>icon.jpg</fileName> 
    <filePath>C:\Program Files\media</filePath> 
    <dateModified>2012-04-30T15:43:31.2995396-05:00</dateModified> 
    <Action>Add</Action> 
  </MediaFile>
</ArrayOfMediaFile>
```

Now my application reads the file name and if the action node is **"add"** it copies the file and converts the action node to **"keep"**.

***The Problem***

What i wish to do now is to save this file after every operation. If while saving the XML there is any error, I should be able to make a copy of the XML which I can again use in the operation.

Comment: Write to disk, add it to a Collection, store in a database, etc. etc.  What are we missing here?  I think you need to explain why "saving" this is different from saving anything?  Are you talking about XML or something else like a DOM object you've loaded the XML into... or what?

Comment: Hey Bob, the XML file is already present on the local disk. I am changing the value of <action> tag each time i copy a file. And then i save the file so that the value in the XML changes. I wanted to know, if while saving the file, the file becomes corrupt, i should be able to have a backup XML ready and then use that file.

Comment: @ Bob Riemersma:And yes...i am loading this file in a DOM object so that i could parse it and perform the required operation by reading the action tag

Comment: If you load it into a DOM object then the DOM object is doing the parsing, not you.  You're merely traversing the DOM tree.  But if you feel you need a "backup copy" then why not just make a copy of the file?  I'm not sure what else you might be asking for.

Comment: You can use `objDoc.selectSingleNode("//action")` to find the node, probably single node and then use `removeChild` and then `appendChild` or `createElement` of the DOM document and then save it to another location as `objDoc.save "c:\sample.xml"`

Comment: Agreed with Bob, just save the file, what is the trouble here. I believe DOMDocument has a Save method? Or are we simply being asked to provide the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code always backs up the XML file .xml to .backup, and then if successful, it saves to _Processed.xml. Hope that's what you want.

```
Private Function ProcessFilesFromXml(ByRef the_sXmlFileName As String) As Boolean

    Dim nPosDot                         As Long
    Dim sXmlFileNamePrefix              As String
    Dim sXmlFileNameSuffix              As String
    Dim oXmlDoc                         As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim oXmlMediaFileNode               As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
    Dim oXmlActionNode                  As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    nPosDot = InStr(1, the_sXmlFileName, ".")

    If (nPosDot) Then
        sXmlFileNamePrefix = Left$(the_sXmlFileName, nPosDot - 1)
        sXmlFileNameSuffix = Mid$(the_sXmlFileName, nPosDot)
    Else
        sXmlFileNamePrefix = the_sXmlFileName
        sXmlFileNameSuffix = vbNullString
    End If

    ' First of all, back up the XML file <XmlFileList>.xml to <XmlFileList>.backup  . Overwrites existing backup file.
    FileCopy the_sXmlFileName, sXmlFileNamePrefix & ".backup"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler_ProcessingXml

    ' Load the Xml file <XmlFileList>.xml
    Set oXmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    oXmlDoc.Load the_sXmlFileName

    ' Iterate through each media file, and try to copy it.
    For Each oXmlMediaFileNode In oXmlDoc.selectNodes("/ArrayOfMediaFile/MediaFile")
        If Not CopyFileNameToLocalMachine(oXmlMediaFileNode.selectSingleNode("fileName").Text, oXmlMediaFileNode.selectSingleNode("filePath").Text) Then
            Set oXmlActionNode = oXmlMediaFileNode.selectSingleNode("Action")
            oXmlActionNode.Text = "keep"
        End If
    Next oXmlMediaFileNode

    ' Save under the name <XmlFileList>_Processed.xml
    oXmlDoc.save sXmlFileNamePrefix & "_Processed" & sXmlFileNameSuffix

    ' Since we got here, things must have been fine.
    ProcessFilesFromXml = True

Return_ProcessingXml:
    '
Exit Function

ErrorHandler_ProcessingXml:
    ProcessFilesFromXml = False
    Resume Return_ProcessingXml

ErrorHandler:
    Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description
End Function

Private Function CopyFileNameToLocalMachine(ByRef the_sFileName As String, ByRef the_sLocalPath As String)
    ' Your code here.
End Function
```